# SQliteOpenHelper Database indexoutofbounds when called from fragment's OnResume

Tags: android, database, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem with SQliteDatabase/OpenHelper/AssetHelper that is difficult to fix because I cannot replicate the error that many of my app users are having on my devices or on any android studio emulated devices, so this code I'm about to show you works for me, but not some others and I don't know why.

My users sometimes get an `indexoutofboundsexception` (I believe) when my app takes a value from a `List` that is populated from a database (in the assets folder). So it seems the database is not loading properly. The problem might be related to the context I'm passing when I get an instance of the DatabaseAccess class `DBProgressAccess` in `OnResume` lifecycle callback of the Fragment.

I haven't tried much to fix the issue only because the crash so rarely occurs (just once on my android 6.0 phone), but I'm getting reports from google of frequent crashing for other android devices (up to and including android 6.0). 
The stack trace I have for the crashes comes from google developers console.

I have a fragment that loads at the startup of the app. In its `showSets12()` method called from `onResume()` (where I see the indexoutofbounds error) I access a database of the users scores:

```java
    private void showSets12()
    {
        DBProgressAccess dbProgressAccess = DBProgressAccess.getInstance(getActivity());
        dbProgressAccess.openUserProgressDb();
        dbProgressAccess.getDayValues();
        int scoreToday = dbProgressAccess.getScores().get(0); <--I think the error comes from this
        ...
        dbProgressAccess.closeUserProgressDb();

    }
```

In the public DBProgressAccess class I have:

```java
public class DBProgressAccess {

    private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private static DBProgressAccess instance;

    private List<String> dates;
    private List<Integer> scores;
    private List<String> times;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "UserProgress";

    public List<Integer> getScores() {return scores;}


    private DBProgressAccess(Context context) {
        this.openHelper = new DBProgressHandler(context);
    }

    public static DBProgressAccess getInstance(Context context)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "getInstance");
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new DBProgressAccess(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }


    /**
     * Open the database connection.
     */
    public void openUserProgressDb() {
        Log.d(TAG, "openUserProgress");
        this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    /**
     * Is todays date included in the database? If not, create it and search the database to populate lists for times and scores
     */
    public void getDayValues()
    {
        if (checkIfDateExists()) {
            Cursor cursor = searchDayProgress();
            searchDatabase(cursor);
        }
        else
        {
            createDayEntry();
            Cursor cursor = searchDayProgress();
            searchDatabase(cursor);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check to see if there is a record in the database for today 
     */
    public boolean checkIfDateExists()
    {
        Cursor cursor = searchDayProgress();
        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0)
        {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Insert todays date into the database
     */
    private void createDayEntry()
    {
        Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String todayString = formatter.format(today);
        int score = 0;
        String time = "0:00:0";

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("date", todayString);
        cv.put("score", score);
        cv.put("time", time);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }


    /**
     * Find the database record for today
     */
    private Cursor searchDayProgress() {
        String whereQuery = "SELECT * FROM UserProgress WHERE date = date('now')";
        Log.d(TAG, "searchWeekProgress " + whereQuery);
        return database.rawQuery(whereQuery, null);
    }

    /**
     * Populate lists of time, date and progress taken from the database
     */
    public void searchDatabase(Cursor cursor)
    {
        List<String> listDate = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> listUserProgress = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listTime = new ArrayList<>();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            listDate.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")));
            listUserProgress.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("score")));
            listTime.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        setDates(listDate);
        setScores(listUserProgress);
        setTimes(listTime);
    }

    private void setDates(List<String> dates) {this.dates = dates;}
    private void setScores(List<Integer> scores) {this.scores = scores;}
    private void setTimes(List<String> times) {this.times = times;}

}
```

I believe the `List<string>` variables turn out to be empty.

I wish I could put in more specific code but the google dev console stack trace is unclear.

The error I get is from the google developers console, not android studio, since I cannot replicate the issue on my devices or any emulated devices.

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3573)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3613)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2862)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1574)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6364)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1076)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:937)

Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:411)
  at org.ieltstutors.academicwordlist.AcademicWordListFragment.showSets12 (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  at org.ieltstutors.academicwordlist.AcademicWordListFragment.access$000 (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .access$200 (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .drawCircularLockedProgress (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .onCreateView (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .openCloseSet (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .showCircularScores (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .showScores (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  or                     .updateScores (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
  at org.ieltstutors.academicwordlist.AcademicWordListFragment.onResume (AcademicWordListFragment.java)
```

Unfortunately, that is all the information I have on the error.

So the IndexOutOfBoundsException comes from showSets12.
Could the error be from using the wrong context for `getInstance`? Or maybe from `getWriteableDatabase`?
Why might the database be accessed correctly some times but not other times? I remember that when the app crashed on my phone when the app started up, I immediately tried to open the app on my friend's phone, but it crashed also, having never crashed before on either. Coincidence?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `getScores()` is returning an empty list. Be prepared for your query to not match any rows.

Comment: Thanks for your message @laalto. The query should always find something since a record is added for the current date if the current date doesn't already exist in the database. This works for my phone and all the emulators I have tried (with many android versions), so I would like to know why the crash occurs for some of my users.

Answer (score 0):

The fragments onResume() or onPause() will be called only when the Activities onResume() or onPause() is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity. if you want to do something when your fragment added to activity you can use OnAttach() or other fragment lifecycles

Read this to understand the Fragment [Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#Lifecycle)

Comment: Hi there Arsalan. Thanks for your input. These were my exact thoughts, so I tested a version with the context getActivity() stored in a variable during OnAttach(). Certain users still reported crashing though. I haven't yet tried calling showSets12() from OnAttach(). The problem is that I have to wait 2 days before the google console begins giving me crash reports to updated code.

Comment: I should add that the method is being called correctly, but I believe the database isn't (occasionally) loading as it should.